# Trigonometric functions what is: $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}f(\cot\theta)\,d\theta$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, change-of-variable

Given that:
$$\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}f(\tan\theta)\,d\theta=2017$$
What is the value of the following integral:
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3}f(\cot\theta)\,d\theta$$

Comment: Also $2017$ because $\cot\theta=\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$. Feels like a brain teaser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the change of variable
$x= \pi/2 -\theta$
$$ 2017 =\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}f(\tan x)\,dx=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}f\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)dx=\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/4}f\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)}{\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)}\right)d\theta \\ \hspace{-4.45cm}=-\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/4}f\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)d\theta=\int^{\pi/3}_{\pi/4}f(\cot\theta)\,d\theta $$

That is

$$ 2017 =\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}f(\tan\theta)\,d\theta =\int^{\pi/3}_{\pi/4}f(\cot\theta)\,d\theta $$

Comment: Where is $x$ gone ?

Comment: We don't care about x put whatever you want there

Comment: See the edit is it ok for you now?

Comment: Do you really need so many steps for $\cot(\pi/2-x)=\tan x$?